# PHP How to update uploaded multiple file in different column in DB table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, upload

I have an HTML form to upload two PDF files. Am able to successfully make it upload one file to a column but not sure how to upload each PDF files to a different column on the database table. Below is my code:

```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                 
$errors = array();
$uploadedFiles = array();
$extension = array("pdf");
$bytes = 5024;
$KB = 5024;
$totalBytes = $bytes * $KB;
$UploadFolder = "UploadFolder";
$counter = 0;


foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
  $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
  $vendor_blicense = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
   
  if(empty($temp))
  {
      break;
  }
   
  $counter++;
  $UploadOk = true;
   
  if($_FILES["files"]["size"][$key] > $totalBytes)
  {
      $UploadOk = false;
      array_push($errors, $vendor_blicense." file size is larger than the 5 MB.");
    echo '<script>alert("File size is larger than the 5 MB...")</script>';
  }
   
  $ext = pathinfo($vendor_blicense, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if(in_array($ext, $extension) == false){
      $UploadOk = false;
      array_push($errors, $vendor_blicense." is invalid file type. Only PDF");
      echo '<script>alert("Invalid file type. Only pdf")</script>';
  }
   
  
   
  if($UploadOk == true){

if(file_exists($UploadFolder."/".$vendor_blicense) == true){
 
$vendor_blicense1 = uniqid().$vendor_blicense;
$success = mysqli_query($kone,$query);


$preparedStatement = $kone->prepare("UPDATE table SET vendor_blicense = :vendor_blicense WHERE vendor_id = '$send_id'");

$preparedStatement->execute([ ':vendor_blicense' => $vendor_blicense1 ]);



        move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$vendor_blicense1);
      array_push($uploadedFiles, $vendor_blicense1);

      }


    else{

$preparedStatement = $kone->prepare("UPDATE table SET vendor_blicense = :vendor_blicense WHERE vendor_id = '$send_id'");

$preparedStatement->execute([ ':vendor_blicense' => $vendor_blicense ]);


      move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$vendor_blicense);
      array_push($uploadedFiles, $vendor_blicense);

    }
  }
}

     }


?>
```

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" accept=".pdf">
<input type="file" id="files2" name="files[]" accept=".pdf">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

```

How can I get the name and PDF files of each input "file" and "files2" and submit to the different column on the database and Uploadfolder on the server? I have a query like this: UPDATE hobber_vendor SET vendor_blicense = :vendor_blicense AND vendor_btax = :vendor_btax  WHERE vendor_id = '$send_id' I want to update vendor_btax to store the name of files from "files2" and also upload the file to   move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$vendor_btax);
array_push($uploadedFiles, $vendor_tax);

Comment: I am having a hard time telling what the actual question/problem is supposed to be here now. You are already looping over your array of files, you are already making UPDATE statements and moving the uploaded file …so what _exactly_ is the part you are having trouble with now?

Comment: (Where `$send_id` is supposed to come from only you can possibly know though, because in the code you have shown I see you only reading from that variable, but not where it is supposed to get a value assigned in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks, am having trouble upload each file from the input to different column.

Comment: I declared $send_id as 1 at the beginning of the code. The major issue is trying to update each file name in different columns e.g file => vendor_blicense and vendor_btax.

Comment: Am able to upload just one filename on a column, am looking for how to update the database with the filename of the other on different column.

Comment: The value of `$key` within your foreach loop is either `0` or `1` (these files are uploaded in the order the input fields had in the form, at least with a normal form submission), so you can use that to differentiate which of the two you are currently dealing with. If you don’t want to rely on the order, you can also _specify_ the key you want to be used on that array level, by using f.e. `name="files[foo]"` and `name="files[bar]"`.

Comment: Can you please help update my code with the correct line

Comment: Please help add it to my code as an answer

Comment: i tried to replace $vendor_blicense = $_FILES["files[foo]"]["name"][$key]; and I got an error.

Comment: Of course, the array key on the first level is still `files`. If you are not sure about the structure of the data you are receiving, then use var_dump or print_r to make a debug output of it.

Comment: Am able to get ["myCheck"] which is the input name from var_dump. So is this the value in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all research, troubleshooting, and following every line of my code. Was able to resolve this by firstly changing my HTML code to below:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files['license']" accept=".pdf">
<input type="file" id="files2" name="files['tax']" accept=".pdf">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then I got value for each input and assign it to each column on the database. Also, I declared the `uniqid()` outside my foreach loop to reuse in case users try to upload files that have the same path name as the one on the server. Below is my complete PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$errors = array();
$uploadedFiles = array();
$extension = array("pdf");
$bytes = 5024;
$KB = 5024;
$totalBytes = $bytes * $KB;
$UploadFolder = "UploadFolder";
$random = uniqid();

foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
  $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
  $filer = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

  $vendor_blicense = $_FILES["files"]["name"]["license"];

  $vendor_btax = $_FILES["files"]["name"]["tax"];

if(empty($temp))
  {
      break;
  }
   
  $counter++;
  $UploadOk = true;
   
  if($_FILES["files"]["size"]["license"] > $totalBytes)
  {
      $UploadOk = false;
      array_push($errors, $vendor_blicense." file size is larger than the 5 MB.");
    echo '<script>alert("File size is larger than the 5 MB...")</script>';
  }
  
  if($_FILES["files"]["size"]["tax"] > $totalBytes)
  {
      $UploadOk = false;
      array_push($errors, $vendor_btax." file size is larger than the 5 MB.");
    echo '<script>alert("File size is larger than the 5 MB...")</script>';
  }
  

  $ext = pathinfo($vendor_blicense, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if(in_array($ext, $extension) == false){
      $UploadOk = false;
      array_push($errors, $vendor_blicense." is invalid file type. Only PDF");
      echo '<script>alert("Invalid file type. Only pdf")</script>';

  }
  
  $ext = pathinfo($vendor_btax, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if(in_array($ext, $extension) == false){
      $UploadOk = false;
      array_push($errors, $vendor_btax." is invalid file type. Only PDF");
      echo '<script>alert("Invalid file type. Only pdf")</script>';

  }
   
  
   
  if($UploadOk == true){

if(file_exists($UploadFolder."/".$filer)){

$filer1 = $random.$filer;
$vendor_blicense1 = $random.$vendor_blicense;
$vendor_btax1 = $random.$vendor_btax;
$success = mysqli_query($kone,$query);


$preparedStatement = $kone->prepare("UPDATE table SET vendor_blicense = :vendor_blicense, vendor_btax = :vendor_btax, vendor_tax_check = :vendor_tax_check,vendor_bstage = :vendor_bstage  WHERE vendor_id = '$send_id'");
$preparedStatement->execute([ ':vendor_blicense' => $vendor_blicense1, ':vendor_btax' => $vendor_btax1, ':vendor_tax_check' => $vendor_tax_check, ':vendor_bstage' => $vendor_bstage]);



        move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$filer1);
      array_push($uploadedFiles, $filer1);

      }


    else{

$preparedStatement = $kone->prepare("UPDATE table SET vendor_blicense = :vendor_blicense, vendor_btax = :vendor_btax, vendor_tax_check = :vendor_tax_check, vendor_bstage = :vendor_bstage WHERE vendor_id = '$send_id'");

$preparedStatement->execute([':vendor_blicense' => $vendor_blicense, ':vendor_btax' => $vendor_btax, ':vendor_tax_check' => $vendor_tax_check, ':vendor_bstage' => $vendor_bstage]);


      move_uploaded_file($temp,$UploadFolder."/".$filer);
      array_push($uploadedFiles, $filer);

    }
  }
}
if($counter>0){
  if(count($errors)>0)
  {
      echo "<b>Errors:</b>";
      echo "<br/><ul>";
      foreach($errors as $error)
      {
          echo "<li>".$error."</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul><br/>";
  }
   
  if(count($uploadedFiles)>0){

echo "successfully uploaded";

}

 
$kone->close();

     }                               
}
else{
  
echo '<script>alert("Please, Select file(s) to upload!")</script>';
echo "<center>Please, Select file(s) to upload!</center>";
}




}


}
```